# Want to create captcha in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
import java.util.Random;
public class MyCaptcha {
    public String GenCaptcha()
    {

        char data[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        char index[]=new char[7];

        Random r=new Random();
        int i =0;

        for( i=0;i<(index.length);i++)
        {
            int ran=r.nextInt(data.length);
            index[i]=data[ran];
            String captcha=String.valueOf(index);
            System.out.println("captcha is"+captcha);
            return captcha;
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that its generating two captcha at a time but i want to create single captcha on refresh help me out in editing this code

Comment: Worked fine for me. Try adding `return null;` after the for.

Comment: 1) Clearly, this code doesn't compile.  2) If you fix the compilation / logic errors, A Java method with return type String can still only ever return one value per call.  So the behavior (generating multiple CAPTCHAs) is not caused by this code.  Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: Hint: the last 3 statements in the loop should be outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a return statement for method GenCaptcha, so that it can not be ran to return 2 captcha. Add a return statement, then your method will run well.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.getCaptcha());
    }

    public String getCaptcha() {
        char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
                'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
                'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
                'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                '7', '8', '9'};
        char index[] = new char[7];

        Random r = new Random();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < (index.length); i++) {
            int ran = r.nextInt(data.length);
            index[i] = data[ran];
        }
        return new String(index);
    }
}
```

This modifies your code a bit, but will get the job done. Hope you find this snippet useful.

EDIT: This code logic can be rewritten to use ASCII value range also, but not posting the code for the same as this will suffice.

Thanks